# Slicing a python dictionary to perform operations

Tags: python, dictionary

New 2.7 user. I have the following dictionary:

```
 dict1 = {'A': {'val1': '5', 'val2': '1'},
          'B': {'val1': '10', 'val2': '10'},
          'C': {'val1': '15', 'val3': '100'}}
```

I have another dictionary

```
 dict2 = {'val1': '10', 'val2': '16'}
```

I want to subtract the values from A in dict1 from dict2 to get:

```
 dict3 = {'val1': '5', 'val2': '15'}
```

Comment: "I attempted to convert the dictionary to an array using np.array(dict1)" - what were you expecting that to do? Arrays don't work like that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with slicing. Extracting `[2,3,4]` from `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` is slicing.

Comment: You want to subtract those strings numerically? Why not store the values as  integers instead? If these are counts, use `Counter` instances, these support subtraction *natively*.

Comment: Also, 'slicing' applies to ordered sequences. Dictionaries are *not* sequences, let alone ordered. What you are asking about has nothing to do with slicing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have been reading more on arrays and did not find much information working with dictionaries. I assumed working with arrays would be much easier. Forgive me for not using the proper terminology (slicing), I am still new at learning Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create your dict using a dict comprehension:

```
d3 = {k: str(int(v) - int(dict1["A"][k])) for k, v in dict2.items()}
print(d3)
```

Which would give you:

```
 {'val2': '15', 'val1': '5'}
```

`for k, v in dict2.items()` iterates over the key/value pairs from *dict2* then we access the corresponding value from *dict1's "A"* dict  with `dict1["A"][k])` and subtract.

If you plan on doing calculations like that you may be as well to store the values as actual ints, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, this should work :

```
# dict1 and dict2 have been initialized
dict3 = {}
for key in dict2:
    dict3[key] = str(int(dict2[key])-int(dict1["A"][key]))
```